# SharePoint BCS with SOAP web service using custom authentication

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs, authentication, soap

I'm very new to using BCS in SharePoint 2010. I'm not really sure how to go about my problem or if it's even possible without coding a custom solution in Visual Studio using .NET.

I have a SOAP web service I want to connect to my SharePoint site in order to create a list containing students retrieved from a request. This seems like a pretty straight forward thing to achieve using **SharePoint Designer** and BCS.

The issue is the way the SOAP interface I'm communicating with deals with authentication (Just to clarify I wasn't the person who initially setup the SOAP service). In order to pull down this list of students I need to first call a soap action called **StartWebService** which takes a username and password as parameters. Then the response from this action is a **session token** which is used as a parameter in the **GetStudentList** action.

How do I deal with authenticating with the StartWebService action and using the result as a parameters in another request? Can this be achieved using SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Designer wouldn't be able to do this.  For your web service call, it only supports regular authentication methods, not calling another service first to get a token.

I see two options:

1) Write a custom BCS provider in Visual Studio that does it

2) Write a custom web service to act as a middle-man that does the multiple calls and presents itself as a simple web service to BCS in SPD.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and advice. I will look into these options.

Comment: You are most certainly welcome.  Welcome to the community.